# Question: passing in dynamic variable into Dockerfile...?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-ecr, dynamic-variables

We have an angular/express app that is dockerized and deployed in k8s.

```
Dockerfile:

FROM node:18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 1234
CMD [ "npm", "run", "prod" ]
```

Is it possible to have a variable and have that variable be dynamic?

Example of what I want:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 1234
CMD [ "npm", "run", ENV ] <<<<<------ HERE (want to pass in either dev or prod)
```

I have a build script (which needs to be run with an arg passed in) that does the following:

- ./build_and_deploy_app.sh dev or ./build_and_deploy_app.sh prod

dev or prod are the variables I want to pass into Dockerfile

- builds docker app
- tags docker app
- pushes docker app to ECR

Once that docker image is pushed to ECR:

- We update our k8s deployment to use the newly uploaded image

I wondering if there is a way to allow our Dockerfile (docker image that is uploaded to ECR) to use a dynamic variable instead of a static variable (like shown above).

Thank you!

Comment: (Building a separate container per environment is something of an anti-pattern; ideally you can run an identical image in all environments.  It's easy to override the `CMD` when you run the container, which may simplify this use case for you.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Docker `ARG` instruction:

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

EXPOSE 1234
ARG env
CMD [ "npm", "run", ${env}]
```

And then pass the value with `--build-arg`:

```
docker build --build-arg env=prod -t mycontainer .
```

And of course, you could take this from the shell script's argument:

```
docker build --build-arg env=$1 -t mycontainer .
```